# broken pipe error returned in paramiko.ssh_exception.ProxyCommandFailure

Tags: paramiko

I am getting broken pipe error for the following code using paramiko

```
 import paramiko
 proxy  = paramiko.ProxyCommand('/usr/bin/nc -vvv  -xhost:1080 %h %p')
 client = paramiko.SSHClient()
 client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
 client.connect('hostname', 22,username='user', password='pwd', sock=proxy)
 stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('ls')
 print "output", stdout.read()
 error = stderr.read()
 print "err", error, len(error)
 ftp = client.open_sftp() 
 ftp.get('file')
 ftp.close()
 client.close()
```

Error I am getting is 
paramiko.ssh_exception.ProxyCommandFailure: ('/usr/bin/nc -vvv -w30 -xhost:1080 %h %p', 'Broken pipe')